# how i pass nested json array object in angular js google map

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new in angular js .I am trying to pass my json lat lon data in to goole api .My json file structure

```
{
 "totalCount":206,
  "deals":[{
       "id":"2",
       "Name":"samir",
       "locations":[{
         "location":"Mundhwa Gaon",
         "address":"Mundhwa Gaon, North Main Road, Pune - 411 001",
          "latLon":"18.53918870,73.90790910"
          },
          "location":"Mundhwa Gaon",
          "address":"Mundhwa Gaon, North Main Road, Pune - 411 001",
          "latLon":"18.53918870,73.90790910"
          },
        ]

   }]
}
```

My angular js code

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/asas}).success(function(data) {             
            $scope.deal = data.deals;               
            if(data.deals.hasOwnProperty("locations") && data.deals.locations!=null){           

                var location=$scope.deal.locations[0]['latLon'];
                var locationlatlong=location.split(",");
                $scope.map = {center: {latitude: locationlatlong[0], longitude: locationlatlong[1] }, zoom: 4 }
                $scope.options = {scrollwheel: false};
                var markers = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.deal.locations.length; i++) {
                    markers.push(createmarker(i, $scope.deal.locations[i]['location'], $scope.deal.locations[i]['latLon'],$scope.deal.locations[i]['address']))
                }
                $scope.markers = markers;
                if(badBrowser){
                    $scope.rendermap=false; 

                }else{                      
                    $scope.rendermap=true;      

                }
            }                               
        });
```

But my if condition not working because of they don't get value . I am using angular js 1.2.23

Comment: Are you sure success is even being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deals` is an array where each element of the array is an object containing the fields for one deal, you should use a loop over `data.deals[i]` to access the data for the i-th deal.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is checking if the deals array has a property of "locations," which it does not. The first *object* in the deals array has a property of "locations." You would either want to iterate over the deals array and run each item through your condition:

```
data.deals.forEach(function(deal) {
  if (deal.locations)...
```

or just check the first item:

```
if(data.deals[0].locations ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass latlon base on deal "id" ?